# Blockcypher Generate Address Endpoint all hex-encoded

Tags: wallets, addresses, python

I'm trying to generate a new eth address in [www.blockcypher.com](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#generate-address-endpoint).

Everything works fine, but the address returns this type `e3f7e628fff7589218d88ae1d6bcdac52fef2168`, but it must start with`0x`, and there is a note `all hex-encoded`.

Tell me, how right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hex-encoded data is often prefixed with `0x` to make it easier for people to recognize it's hex in some contexts. But that's all it is: a prefix. As all the binary data in BlockCypher APIs is hex-encoded anyway, it's just not returned with the address.

But if you need it for any other service, just add the `0x` in front of the returned address and it will work.